inverse of a rational / irrational defined function
Going through Spivak's chapter on inverse functions, there is an interesting problem:
Find $f^{-1}$ if:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if } x  \text{ is rational} \\
-x & \text{if } x \text{ is irrational}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, $f(x)$ is not one-one, because we can find a rational b, such that f(b) = f(-b) = b. Therefore function $f^{-1}$ does not exist. But in a broader meaning that $f^{-1}$ is a set, we can define it.
$$f^{-1} = \left\{(0, 0)\right\} \cup \left\{(x, x) : x \in \mathbb{Q}^+\right\} \cup \left\{(x, -x) : x \in \mathbb{Q}^-\right\} \cup \left\{(-x, x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \setminus \mathbb{Q}\right\} \cup \left\{(-x, -x) : x \in \mathbb{R}^- \setminus \mathbb{Q}\right\}$$
Is this correct?

Your claim (and alledged proof) that $f$ is not one-one is false, as well as you "set $f^{-1}$". In fact, $f^{-1}=f$.

if we take, concretely, b = 1/2, then f(1/2) = f(-1/2) = 1/2. And that violates the "horizontal line" test.

No, $f(-1/2)=-1/2$.

ah, you are right

$f\circ f=id$. So, again: $f^{-1}=f$.

did you mean $f^{-1} \circ f = id$ ?

No, I meant what I wrote, which proved my (repeated) claim.

how does $f \circ f = id$, let us prove that $f^{-1} = f$?

For any functions $f:A\to B, g:B\to A$, [$f$ is bijective and $f^{-1}=g$] iff [$g\circ f=id_A$ and $f\circ g=id_B$].

$f$ is one-one. To prove it, suppose these exist $x,y\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. If $x,y\in\mathbb Q$, then $f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$. Similarly, if $x,y\in\mathbb R\smallsetminus\mathbb Q$, $f(x)=f(y) \iff -x = -y \iff x = y$. Therefore, $f$ is injective. It's also surjective, that is a trivial result: for any $x\in\mathbb R$, $f(f(x))=x$.
Thus, $f$ is a bijection and $f^{-1} = f$.

I think you meant to say surjective after you have proven injectivity, of course.

@PotusOtis ah yeah, thanks for pointing it out.

i have noticed spivak does not use concepts of surjectivity and bijectivity in his book at all. is that the case then, that if the function is a bijection, then f^-1 = f?

@Naz in general, a function is a bijection if and only if it's invertible. Functions $f$ such that $f = f^{-1}$ are special cases. Examples are $y=x$, $y=a-x$ and $y=1/x$. In this case, the function is defined piecewise, by two functions equal to their inverse. So this property is "inherited" by $f$.

You miss the case where $x\in \Bbb Q$ and $y\in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$

Your claim (and alledged proof) that $f$
is not one-one is false, as well as you "set $f^{−1}$". In fact, $f^{−1}=f$ since $f\circ f=id$.
More generally, for any functions $$f:A\to B\quad\text{and}\quad g:B\to A,$$
[$f$ is bijective and $f^{−1}=g$]
if and only if
[$g\circ f=id_A$ and $f\circ g=id_B$].
